# Handeling Cookies With the Broswer Control in C#

Tags: c#, automation, httpwebrequest, webbrowser-control

I am automating a process on the website. For simplicity sake, lets say there are two parts to the process. The first is logging into site and the second is clicking a button on the page. I believe that the login mechanism uses a cookie to handle authentication. I have used Fiddler and was able to view this cookie.

The issue I have is that as of now, I can automate the login and clicking the button, but I can only do it for one control. I only have one login and the system does not allow me to login again using another browser. What I want to do is issue multiple request to click the button at the same time. But right now I am stuck doing them sequentially.

Is there a way that I can get the cookies from the Browser control and use it for other web requests?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own request using `HttpRequest` and response object.

The function below might help you regarding this. By using this, you don't need to login again and again, you just add cookies to the request which will provide authentication and you just send requests in loop:

```
public static bool SessionRequest(Fiddler.Session oS, ref string htmlContent, string requestMethod)
{

    try
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(oS.fullUrl);

        if (oS != null && oS.oRequest.headers != null && oS.oRequest.headers.Count() > 0)
        {
            NameValueCollection coll = new NameValueCollection();
            request.Headers = new WebHeaderCollection();
            foreach (Fiddler.HTTPHeaderItem rh in oS.oRequest.headers)
            {
                if (rh.Name.Contains("Cookie"))
                {
                    ((HttpWebRequest)request).CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                    string[] cookies = UtilitiesScreenScrapper.UtilityMethods.SplitString(rh.Value, ";");
                    if (cookies != null && cookies.Length > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (string c in cookies)
                        {
                            string[] cookie = UtilitiesScreenScrapper.UtilityMethods.SplitString(c, "=");
                            if (cookie != null && cookie.Length > 0)
                            {
                                cookie[0] = cookie[0].Replace(" ", "%");
                                cookie[1] = cookie[1].Replace(" ", "%");

                                ((HttpWebRequest)request).CookieContainer.Add(new Uri(oS.fullUrl), new Cookie(cookie[0].Trim(), cookie[1].Trim()));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string[] cookie = UtilitiesScreenScrapper.UtilityMethods.SplitString(rh.Value, "=");
                        if (cookie != null && cookie.Length > 0)
                        {
                            ((HttpWebRequest)request).CookieContainer.Add(new Uri(oS.url), new Cookie(cookie[0], cookie[1]));
                        }
                    }

                }

                else if (rh.Name.Contains("User-Agent"))
                {
                    ((HttpWebRequest)request).UserAgent = rh.Value;
                }
                else if (rh.Name.Contains("Host"))
                {
                    ((HttpWebRequest)request).Host = "www." + oS.host;
                }
                else if (rh.Name.Equals("Accept"))
                {
                    ((HttpWebRequest)request).Accept = rh.Value;
                }
                else if (rh.Name.Contains("Content-Type"))
                {
                    ((HttpWebRequest)request).ContentType = rh.Value;
                }
                else if (rh.Name.Contains("Content-Length"))
                {
                    ((HttpWebRequest)request).ContentLength = oS.RequestBody.Length;
                }
                else if (rh.Name.Contains("Connection"))
                {
                    //((HttpWebRequest)request).Connection = rh.Value;

                }
                else if (rh.Name.Equals("Referer"))
                {
                    ((HttpWebRequest)request).Referer = oS.host;
                }
                else
                {

                    ((HttpWebRequest)request).Headers.Add(rh.Name + ":");
                    ((HttpWebRequest)request).Headers[rh.Name] = rh.Value;

                }

            }
            ((HttpWebRequest)request).Headers.Add("Conneciton:");
            ((HttpWebRequest)request).Headers["Conneciton"] = "keep-alive";
            ((HttpWebRequest)request).AllowAutoRedirect = true;


            Stream dataStream;
            if (oS.RequestBody.Length > 0)
            {
                request.Method = "POST";
                // Get the request stream.
                dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                // Write the data to the request stream.
                dataStream.Write(oS.RequestBody, 0, oS.RequestBody.Length);
                // Close the Stream object.
                dataStream.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                request.Method = "GET";
            }
            //string postData = string.Empty;
            //byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
            //request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            // Get the response.
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            //resp = response;
            // Display the status.
            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // Display the content.
            //Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            htmlContent = responseFromServer;
            // Clean up the streams.
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();

        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return false;

}
```